# ggplot annotation - superscript with paste

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been through all the top posts on ggplot superscript in annotation (expression, bquote, etc), and none have done the trick. Appreciate your help.

```
df <- data.frame(x =  rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
var1<-"SR"
var2<-10
mylabel<-paste(var1," at ", var2, "m^2 scale")

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x = mean(df$x), y = mean(df$y),label = "test", parse=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have blank spaces in an expression,

```
mylabel <- sprintf("%s~at~%s~m^2~scale", var1, var2)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Superscripts always trip me up - there always seems to be an exception. Thanks for the interesting solution though - takes me back to my C++ days.